# Can't figure out how to echo a simple string from my object

Tags: php, class, object, soap

I'm new to objects and classes but I'm trying to make a class for one of my simple soap requests so I can call up the status of a job with only the job number. I can't tell how to use the status result even though I can confirm it is working.

Here is what's in my class

```
public function validatejob() {
        $client = new SoapClient('http://server/Service.asmx?wsdl');
        $user = array("Username" => "", "Password" => "");
        $jobnumber = $this->jobnumber;
        $response1 = $client->GetSummaryJobStatus(
          array(
            "Credentials" => $user,
            "JobNumber" => $jobnumber,
            ));
        //$response1 -> GetSummaryJobStatusResult;
        echo $response1 -> GetSummaryJobStatusResult;
}
```

Here is what's on my page:

```
$soap = new Soap; //create a new instance of the Users class
$soap->storeFormValues( $_POST ); 
$soap->validatejob();
print_r($soap->$response1->GetSummaryJobStatusResult);
```

This gets printed on the page:

```
HISTORY Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /home/shawmutw/public_html/client/support.php on line 10
```

You can see that it fails, but HISTORY is the result I'm looking for. How do I properly echo the HISTORY part or store it on a variable to use?

Comment: `$soap->response1->GetSummaryJobStatusResult['Credentials']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a class property and assign the response to it like this:

```
class A {
    public $response1;

    public function validateJob() {
        ...
        $this->response1 = $client->GetSummaryJobStatus(
        ...
    }   
}
```

Then you can access your class property through your instance like this:

```
print_r($soap->response1->GetSummaryJobStatusResult);
```

Comment: No, this class is not necessary unless you define a classmap for the SoapClient. PHP itself will create a bunch of arrays and stdClass objects if no classmap defines otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your method "validateJob" does not return anything, and it does not store the result in any property, so there is no way to access it outside this method.

```
return $response1; // will help inside the method

$job = $soap->validateJob(); // save result

var_dump($job); // see what you get.
```